# ssmtp - can I whitelist recipients so that I do not accidentally email customers from my dev system?

Tags: ssmtp

I use ssmtp to test emails sent from my development web server. Sometimes I want to test things that went wrong for a customer and need to use their email address to bring up records etc. on a test system. What I really don't want is to inadvertently email them.

Therefore is it possible with ssmtp to configure it to only send emails to a whitelist of my own email boxes?